# C++ program that uses std::future refuses to run on Windows XP Embedded

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, embedded

If I `#include <future>` in my program and use `std::async` the program refuses to run on Windows XP Embedded. Now I know that XPE is based on XP SP2 and I read somewhere that you need SP3 in order to take full advantage of multi-threading applications on Win XP, is that correct? Is there anything I can do to patch my XPE to make it run multi-threading applications? When I open the task manager I see two CPU graphs, the processor is an ATOM D2500 @ 1,86 GHz and the specs say it's dual-core / 2 threads.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has supported multithreading since before Windows 2000, literally for decades. Sure, you may get a few % more performance on newer Windows versions.

The more practical problem is that XP is old and `<future>` is new. The C++11 library you use won't run on XP.

As a workaround, use an older compiler (VS2010 perhaps?) and get the Boost library for threading. The C++11 threading design is based on Boost.

Comment: Does Boost contain all the threading features in C++11? I have been using shared_ptr from Boost for a while, but not tried the other features yet.

Comment: @KevinXi: Tricky to answer, because quite a bit of Boost code checks compiler macro's to conditionally support some features. So even if Boost would support all C++11 threading features, that does not imply it does so when Boost is compiled with VS2010.

Comment: Make sense now, whatever the implementation is after macro switch, as long as they work the same way and more importantly not rely on an additional dll file, then I would love it.